# SignalR .NET Client: Handle Broadcast Across Connections When Excluding a Connection

Tags: c#, signalr.client

I am writing unit tests for my SignalR hubs and using the SignalR .NET client (version 2.3.0) to carry out the tests, but I am not able to get other connections to receive a broadcast when the current connection is excluded from the broadcast.

The hub method is making a broadcast as such:

```
Clients.Group(groupName, Context.ConnectionId).sendMessage("A message");
```

My test is configured to have 2 connections to the hub and each connection will call a hub method that will put the connection into `groupName`. I then have a `HubConnection.On` event to handle the broadcast the hub method makes, the result of which is then used to assert the test. This might be clearer explained in code (I have removed some AddBroadcast overloads for brevity):

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to handle the connection, calling of methods and broadcast for a SignalR hub
/// </summary>
public class HubManager
{
    public enum Froms
    {
        Other1,
        Other2
    }

    private HubConnection hubConnection = null;
    private IHubProxy hub = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The outcome of the broadcast that is made
    /// </summary>
    public object Result { get; private set; } = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The connection ID of this hub connection
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionID { get { return this.hubConnection.ConnectionId; } } 

    public HubManager(string h)
    {
        //Create the SignalR connection
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://mywebsite.com");

        //Gain access to the hub
        this.hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(h);

        //Start the connection up and wait for it to complete
        this.hubConnection.Start()
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Error opening the hub connection ({h}): {task.Exception.GetBaseException()}");
                }
            })
            .Wait();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcast a message to clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">The name of broadcast message</param>
    public void AddBroadcast(string methodName)
    {
        this.hub.On(methodName, () => {
            this.Result = methodName;
        });
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcast a message to clients
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">The name of broadcast message</param>
    public void AddBroadcast<T>(string methodName)
    {
        this.hub.On<T>(methodName, _1 => {
            this.Result = _1;
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes a specific hub method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">The name of the hub method to invoke</param>
    /// <param name="args">The parameters for the method</param>
    public void CallMethod(string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        this.hub.Invoke(methodName, args)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Error calling hub method {methodName}: {task.Exception.GetBaseException()}");
                }
            })
            .Wait();
    }
}
```

Usage case:

```
//Create a dictionary to hold the connections
var hubManagers = new Dictionary<HubManager.Froms, HubManager>();
hubManagers.Add(HubManager.Froms.Other1, new HubManager(hubName));
hubManagers.Add(HubManager.Froms.Other2, new HubManager(hubName));

//Call HubMethod1 which will add the connection to the same group
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other1].CallMethod("HubMethod1", user1ID);
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].CallMethod("HubMethod1", user2ID);

//Set a broadcast handle for the second connection (Other2)
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].AddBroadcast<string, string>("callbackMethod");

//Make a hub method call (from Other1) to cause the callbackMethod to run
//As from above, the Other1 connection should not receive it but Other2 should
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other1].CallMethod("HubMethod2", user1ID);

//Get the broadcast result for the second connection (Other2)
var result = hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].Result;

//result == null
```

I have tried using the `AdddBroadcast` on the following combinations and each case results in `result` being null: `Other1`, `Other2` and `Other1` & `Other2`.

If I change `Clients.Group(groupName, Context.ConnectionId).sendMessage("A message");` to not exclude the current connection (`Clients.Group(groupName).sendMessage("A message");`) and I use `AddBroadcast` on  `Other2`, `result` contains the expected value.

The process works as expected on the live system (using ASP.NET and JavaScript) where the calling connection does not get sent the `sendMessage` but the other members of the group do.

Any ideas on how I make the second SignalR .NET client connection receive the broadcast when the first connection is excluded from the broadcast are very much welcomed!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr Here is Microsoft description of Broadcasting. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks @Artavazd that's a great tutorial, but unfortunately I can't see anything in there that indicates what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I realised that the `this.hub.On` event was firing, but after the call to get the result (`var result = hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].Result;`). I therefore added a crude wait method (which I am not massively proud of!) and that has done the trick.

New method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wait for up to 5 seconds for the broadcast to complete
/// </summary>
public void WaitForBroadcastResult()
{
    bool stop = false;
    const double WAIT_FOR = 5D;
    DateTime started = DateTime.Now;
    while (!stop)
    {
        if (this.Result != null || (DateTime.Now - started).TotalSeconds >= WAIT_FOR)
        {
            stop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
...
//Set a broadcast handle for the second connection (Other2)
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].AddBroadcast<string, string>("callbackMethod");

//Make a hub method call (from Other1) to cause the callbackMethod to run
//As from above, the Other1 connection should not receive it but Other2 should
hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other1].CallMethod("HubMethod2", user1ID);

//Wait for the broadcast to complete
this.HubManagers[_HubManager.Froms.Other2].WaitForBroadcastResult();

//Get the broadcast result for the second connection (Other2)
var result = hubManagers[HubManager.Froms.Other2].Result;
```

If anybody has a better idea, then I'm all ears!